# Как лучше создать такую ячейку?

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте!

Вопрос в следующем, хочу сделать при ландшафтной ориентации экрана меню слева из пяти пунктов, стандартными методами плохо выходит с масштабирование и решил сделать следующим образом. Вертикальный LinearLayout разбить на пять одинаковых LinearLayout или RelativeLayout и в каждую ячейку поместить по прямоугольнику занимающему объем всей ячейки и  разделенному на две половины, нижняя половина с текстом и фиксированной высотой, верхняя половина содержит картинку заполняющую весь объем. Так же в нижней и верхней части будет background или чучше его сделать в LinearLayout или RelativeLayout там где будут находиться прямоугольники, картинки с прозрачным фоном. Как лучше это реализовать?

Может через Bitmap или отдельным XML файлом и вставлять через merge.... Подскажите, пожалуйста, если можно с примером. Это все делается, для того, что бы при различных разрешениях нормально масштабировалась картинка и ничего не куда не залазило. Можно, что бы картинка просто была по центру в своей ячейке

[image]

Вот мой код, который я изменяю

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/bg_button2">

        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="33dp"
               android:background="@drawable/bg_header"/>


        <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="0.2">
        <Button android:id="@+id/homeButton"
                android:layout_width="55dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_home_g"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_button2"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:text="@string/str_base_activity_toolbar_home"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="55dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="0.2">
            <Button android:id="@+id/assignedButton"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_trailer_inspection_g"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_button2"
                    style="@style/buttonFont"
                    android:text="@string/str_base_activity_toolbar_assigned"/>
            <TextView   android:id="@+id/assignedButtonCounter" android:layout_alignTop="@id/assignedButton" android:layout_alignRight="@id/assignedButton"
                        android:text="2" android:visibility="gone"
                        style="@style/buttonBadge"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="55dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="0.2">
            <Button android:id="@+id/availableButton"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_available_g"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_button2"
                    style="@style/buttonFont"
                    android:text="@string/str_base_activity_toolbar_available"/>
            <TextView   android:id="@+id/availableButtonCounter" android:layout_alignTop="@id/availableButton" android:layout_alignRight="@id/availableButton"
                        android:text="2234" android:visibility="gone"
                        style="@style/buttonBadge"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="55dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="0.2">
            <Button android:id="@+id/completedButton"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_completed_g"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_button2"
                    style="@style/buttonFont"
                    android:text="@string/str_base_activity_toolbar_completed"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="55dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="0.2">
            <Button android:id="@+id/mailButton"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_mail_g"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_button2"
                    style="@style/buttonFont"
                    android:text="@string/str_base_activity_toolbar_mail"/>
            <TextView   android:id="@+id/mailButtonCounter" android:layout_alignTop="@id/mailButton" android:layout_alignRight="@id/mailButton"
                        android:text="2" android:visibility="gone"
                        style="@style/buttonBadge"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Правильно ли я понял, у меня есть код Активити (это кусок кода)

```
public enum ButtonType
    {
        Home,
        AssignedLoads,
        AvailableLoads,
        CompletedLoads,
        Mail
    }



    tv_title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_title);   
    private Button homeButton;
    private Button assignedButton;
    private Button availableButton;
    private Button completedButton;
    private Button mailButton;
    private TextView assignedButtonCounter;
    private TextView availableButtonCounter;
    private TextView mailButtonCounter;
    private LinearLayout parentLinearLayout;



    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onCreate");

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.base_activity);        

        //buttons
        homeButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.homeButton);
        assignedButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.assignedButton);
        availableButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.availableButton);
        completedButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.completedButton);
        mailButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mailButton);

        //Counters
        assignedButtonCounter = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.assignedButtonCounter);
        availableButtonCounter = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.availableButtonCounter);
        mailButtonCounter = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mailButtonCounter);

        parentLinearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.parentLinearLayout);

        homeButton.setOnClickListener(listenerToolBar_OnClick);
        assignedButton.setOnClickListener(listenerToolBar_OnClick);
        availableButton.setOnClickListener(listenerToolBar_OnClick);
        completedButton.setOnClickListener(listenerToolBar_OnClick);
        mailButton.setOnClickListener(listenerToolBar_OnClick);

        setBadges();
    }




    void setActiveButton(ButtonType button, boolean bEnabled)
    {

        Resources resources = getResources();
        Button b;

        switch (button)
        {
            case AssignedLoads:
                b = assignedButton;
                b.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_trailer_inspection),  null, null );
                break;

            case AvailableLoads:
                b = availableButton;
                b.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_available), null, null);
                break;

            case CompletedLoads:
                b = completedButton;
                b.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_completed), null, null);
                break;

            case Mail:
                b = mailButton;
                b.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_mail), null, null);
                break;

            default:
                b = homeButton;
                b.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_home), null, null);
                break;
        }

        b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_button_selected);
        b.setClickable(bEnabled);
    }

    void setBadges()
    {
        Integer count = MailItemData.getUnreadMailCount(getApplicationContext());
        mailButtonCounter.setText(count.toString());
        mailButtonCounter.setVisibility(count > 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);

        count = TripData.getNewAvailableLoadsCount(getApplicationContext());
        availableButtonCounter.setText(count.toString());
        availableButtonCounter.setVisibility(count > 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);

        count = TripData.getAssignedLoadsCount(getApplicationContext());
        assignedButtonCounter.setText(count.toString());
        assignedButtonCounter.setVisibility(count > 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    }       
}
```

Я меняю его так:

```
public enum ButtonType
{
    Home,
    AssignedLoads,
    AvailableLoads,
    CompletedLoads,
    Mail
}



tv_title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_title);   
private ImageView homeButton;
private ImageView assignedButton;
private ImageView availableButton;
private ImageView completedButton;
private ImageView mailButton;
private TextView assignedButtonCounter;
private TextView availableButtonCounter;
private TextView mailButtonCounter;
private LinearLayout parentLinearLayout;



public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onCreate");

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.base_activity);        

    //ImageViews
    homeButton = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.homeButton);
    assignedButton = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.assignedButton);
    availableButton = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.availableButton);
    completedButton = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.completedButton);
    mailButton = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.mailButton);

    //Counters
    assignedButtonCounter = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.assignedButtonCounter);
    availableButtonCounter = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.availableButtonCounter);
    mailButtonCounter = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mailButtonCounter);

    parentLinearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.parentLinearLayout);

    homeButton.setOnClickListener(listenerToolBar_OnClick);
    assignedButton.setOnClickListener(listenerToolBar_OnClick);
    availableButton.setOnClickListener(listenerToolBar_OnClick);
    completedButton.setOnClickListener(listenerToolBar_OnClick);
    mailButton.setOnClickListener(listenerToolBar_OnClick);

    setBadges();
}




void setActiveButton(ButtonType ImageView, boolean bEnabled)
{

    Resources resources = getResources();
    Button b;

    switch (ImageView)
    {
        case AssignedLoads:
            b = assignedButton;
    ImageView b = new ImageView(context);
    b.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_trailer_inspection);
    b.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(10, 10));
    b.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
    b.setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);                
            break;

        case AvailableLoads:
            b = availableButton;
    b.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_available);
    b.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(10, 10));
    b.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
    b.setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);                
            break;

        case CompletedLoads:
            b = completedButton;
    b.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_completed);
    b.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(10, 10));
    b.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
    b.setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);                
            break;

        case Mail:
            b = mailButton;     
    b.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_mail);
    b.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(10, 10));
    b.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
    b.setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);                
            break;

        default:
            b = homeButton;
    b.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_home);
    b.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(10, 10));
    b.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
    b.setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);                
            break;
    }

    b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_button_selected);
    b.setClickable(bEnabled);
}

void setBadges()
{
    Integer count = MailItemData.getUnreadMailCount(getApplicationContext());
    mailButtonCounter.setText(count.toString());
    mailButtonCounter.setVisibility(count > 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);

    count = TripData.getNewAvailableLoadsCount(getApplicationContext());
    availableButtonCounter.setText(count.toString());
    availableButtonCounter.setVisibility(count > 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);

    count = TripData.getAssignedLoadsCount(getApplicationContext());
    assignedButtonCounter.setText(count.toString());
    assignedButtonCounter.setVisibility(count > 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
}    
}
```

А теперь в XML файле button заменить на `ImageView` (конечно, с небольшой правкой кода)

Я правильно понял???

Comment: ХэшКод, спасибо!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Чтобы масштабировать рисунок внутри вида требуемым образом, можно указывать [ImageView.ScaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html), например,

```
ImageView iv = new ImageView(context);
iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
iv.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(10, 10));
iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
iv.setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);
```

Кроме того, существует поддержка векторной графики: [svg-android](http://code.google.com/p/svg-android/) - можно нарисовать изображения в векторе и масштабировать по желанию.

Comment: @zesen, Если вам ответили верно, следует отметить ответ как принятый.

Comment: Expert, я сегодня опробую этот вариант + как отметить ответ как принятый? Я кликнул на мне нравиться это собщение

Comment: @zesen, для того чтобы принять ответ нужно кликнуть на **галочку** рядом с ответом.

Comment: К сожалению не помогло